# Serving static on nginx file return 403

Tags: nginx

I know there is a lot of questions like this one and I've tried solutions of a lot of them unsuccessfully :(

I'm trying to run a server serving static file and reverse-proxying them in a specific url but when i connect to the url (*perso.xxxxxxx.com*) I got a 403.

Here is what I have:

**beginning of nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
...
```

**conf.d/perso.conf**

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   server_name perso.xxxxxxx.com www.perso.xxxxxxx.com;

   location / {
       autoindex on;
       root /www/perso/public;
   }
}
```

**result of `namei -om /www/perso/public/`**

```
f: /www/perso/public/
 drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
 drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data www
 drw-r--r-- www-data www-data perso
 drw-r--r-- www-data www-data public
```

(the user www-data seems to have all the read permissions needed)

I have restarted nginx with both `nginx -s reload` and `service nginx restart`

Any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: Directories usually need an `x` permission too. Missing from your `perso` and `public` directories.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks a bunch that fixed it indeed directories not X to list files or something. Sry I'm not really familiar with the linux permissions :s
You can post your answer if you wish, I'll gladly accept it.